# Direct migration of questions to appropriate site with specific tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, migration

This question uses Drupal SE site as an example, but may apply to other such cases as well.

As we have a fully launched [Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) site (with a age of 1y7m), can we just migrate any question being asked on SO with tag [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) to this site directly? Instead of going and flagging each question, direct migration would be good.

Just take a look at this link - [latest drupal posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal?sort=newest&pagesize=30). It would be good if they are placed on the Drupal SE site itself, as it would park the information at correct place and would reduce it's content on SO.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Drupal may be a correct place, but as long as SO is not the wrong place, there is no reason to migrate.

Comment: I don't see why people are down voting this? Doesn't 2 places for same questions seem redudant to anyone ?

Comment: Somewhat redundant, yes. Does that mean we should strictly enforce mutual exclusivity? Not really. And it would be very hard if not impossible to do so anyway.

Comment: Ok. I too don't advise for strictly enforcing this. But could it be possible to show a notification to the user that "This question would best suite on *Drupal* and would get faster response" while he is about to ask a question tagged with 'Drupal'. This would also create awareness about the active Drupal site. What are your thoughts?

Comment: For Drupal that is already part of the tag wiki excerpt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't generally batch-migrate, for a number of reasons:

- Migration of old questions is discouraged; we prefer that new communities grow organically from questions that are asked on their own site, not from questions that were posted to the wrong site ages ago.
- Questions are only migrated when they are *stellar* questions that are *clearly off-topic* on the site they were asked.

Consequently, migrations are always handled on a case-by-case basis.